# Add shape to Word document from Excel: "Type mismatch" caused by doc.shapes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a shape to a Word document from Excel.

In this sub I get the error

> Type mismatch

in

```
Set stampShape = objDoc.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 126.75, 611.25, 303.75, 44.25)
```

The error is caused by `objDoc.Shapes`.

```vb
Private Sub Insert_Stamp(objDoc As Document)
    Dim stampShape As Shape

    ' Add rounded rectangle shape
    Set stampShape = objDoc.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 126.75, 611.25, 303.75, 44.25)
    
    ' Set shape properties
    With stampShape
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red border color
        .Line.Weight = 3
        .Fill.Transparency = 1#
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "BETAALD PER PIN"
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 24
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    End With

End Sub
```

The sub is called in this sub, which is called from a Form.
Me.F_Confirmation contains a valid file name of an existing Word document:

```vb
Private Sub F_MerkFactuurAlsCash_Click()
    Dim FactuurNaam As String
    Dim objDoc As Object
    
    FactuurNaam = Me.F_Confirmation
    
    'Open factuurfile
    Set objDoc = FactuurDocumentFunctions.OpenFactuurFile(FactuurNaam)
    
    'Zet Watermerk

    Insert_Stamp objDoc
    
    'Formulier sluiten
    Unload Me
    
End Sub
```

The `objDoc` is generated by this function:

```vb
Function OpenFactuurFile(filename As String) As Document
Dim FilePath As String

'Vind path huidige folder en creer pad naar file
    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    FilePath = FilePath & "\" & F_Folder & "\" & filename
' Use Dir to check if file exists
    If Dir(FilePath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Deze file bestaat niet " & FilePath
            Exit Function
    End If
'Open factuurfile
   If Not IsWordRunning Then
        Set Globals.objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Globals.objWord.Visible = True
   Else
        Set Globals.objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   End If
   
   Set OpenFactuurFile = Globals.objWord.Documents.Open(FilePath)
End Function
```

Finally `Globals.objWord` is a line in a module with global variables:

```vb
Public objWord As Object
```

Comment: `Shape` likely defaults to `Excel.Shape` which may not be the same as `Word.Shape`, so try using `As Object` if you're using late binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is in Excel VBA modules, you need

- Add reference: VBE Tools->Reference->Check `Microsoft Word x.0 Object Library`
- Change the code as below.

```
Private Sub Insert_Stamp(objDoc As Word.Document)
    Dim stampShape As Word.Shape
```

Comment: I had teh library already included, but did not know I had add "Word." to objects in the Word Document. Thanx.